# optimal solution for a modified version of the bin-packing task

Tags: algorithm, backtracking, greedy

**Problem**

Suppose we have a set of *N* real numbers  *A = {x_1, x_2, ..., x_N}*.

The goal is to partition this set into *A_1, A_2, ..., A_L* subsets with the limitation of *sum( A_i ) <= T* and **minimizing** this term:

*Cost := sum( abs( sum(A_i) - T ) )*

where *sum(A_i)* denotes the summation of numbers in *A_i* and *T* is a given threshold.

*I am looking for a non-evolutionary optimal algorithm.*

**Update:** *x_i* are real positive numbers and not greater than *T* ( *0 < x_i <= T* ).

**Update 2:** The cost function fixed.

---

**Nice try, Greedy algorithm!**

A simple idea is to use a [Greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) approach to solve the problem. Here is a pseudocode:

```
 1. create subset A_1 and set i=1.
 2. remove the largest number x from A.
 3. If sum(A_i) + x <= T
  * put x into A_i
 4. Else
  * create a new subset A_i+1, 
  * put x into A_i+1 
  * set i=i+1
 5. If A is non-empty
  * goto step 2.
 6. Else
  * return all created A_i s
```

The problem is this solution is not optimal. For example, there are cases that it is better not to put two largest numbers, *x1* and *x2*, in the first subset *A_1* even they don't exceed *T*, because there is no other *x_i* available to add to that set and make its sum closer to *T*. In the other hand, if we had put *x1* and *x2* in the separate sets, a better solution could be found (a solution with smaller *Cost* value).

**Possible solutions**

I have thought of using a [Backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) algorithm which can find the optimal solution too, but I guess its complexity in this problem would be high.

I have read some article on Wikipedia like [Bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) (NP-hard *[sighs...]*) and [Cutting stock problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) and apparently my problem is very similar to this standard problems, but I am not sure which one matches my case.

Comment: For what i understood, it looks like you have to solve several knapsack problems, i mean, solve a knapsack for T, so you get a set A_1 that has min cost, but close enought to T, and then you run a knapsack again (removing the A_0 elements from A) so you get a new A_1 optimal and close to T, then you repeat again until you find all the A_i

Comment: @h3nr1x: I guess this is what greedy solution does. While this approach finds optimal solutions for each knapsack, it fails to find a global optimum solution (An example is given in the question).

Comment: There is something wrong with the term to minimize because it is constant regardless of how the sets are partitioned. It is always equivalent to the sum of all N numbers minus T times L.

Comment: @antti.huima: Good point. I guess this term is just minimzing the number of subests. For example, it prevents the solution where only one *x_i* is placed in every set. Anyway, I am not sure if this is the only role of minimizing term.

Comment: @Isaac you can't but x_i in every set if you are looking for a "partition" as you write. Partition implies that the sets are disjoint. If you can have the same element in multiple sets it is not a partition but just a set of subsets.

Comment: @antti.huima: I meant to put *x_1* in first subset, *x_2* in the next subset, and so on. So we end up with *N* subsets. Sorry for the bad choice of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
With the corrected cost function, note that sum(A_i) - T will always be negative as A_i <= T.
So our objective is to minimize

sum(abs(sum(A_i)-T)) = sum(T-sum(A_i)) = L*T-sum(A)

sum(A) is constant, so the task is to minimize the number of used bins. Therefore your problem is equivalent to classic bin packing.

For solving this you could use a bin packing solver like [this one](http://scip.zib.de/doc/examples/Binpacking/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I made a mistake in the definition of cost function and omitted a `abs`. The question is now updated.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer and providing a proving.